# How to call addClass() on all body elements using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to call `.addClass` on all elements that are direct children of body. How would I do this?

Comment: You have more than one body element?

Comment: @Šime you might notice the OP has 559 questions and 4 answers (still, I agree)

Comment: @All - Fixed the question a bit. Sory for not explaining what I needed in more detailed way... but as @Zirak noticed there is no more than 1 `<body>` tag in html page.. so I really thought it was clear. BTW thanks to @Harpyon for grate answer.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It's a bit unclear what you mean. This will call it on all `<body>` tags (hopefully you only have one):

```
$("body").addClass("some-class")
```

If you need to call it on all descendants of `body`, i.e. all elements:

```
$("body *").addClass("some-class")
```

Or, if you want to call `.addClass` on all elements that are direct children of `body`:

```
$("body > *").addClass("some-class")
```

Comment: Can we call `.removeClass` on all elements that are direct children of `body` using `$("body > *")`?

Comment: @Blender, yes. `$("body > *")` is simply a selector. It picks all the elements, to which you can do anything, including `removeClass`.

Comment: Wouldn't you generally want to do `$("body").addClass("some-class")` in your JavaScript, and then have a line like `body.some-class *` in your css? Just wondering which would be better performance wise, iterating over all of the descendents of body could be quite slow indeed.

Answer (score 4):

Use this instead

```
$("body").children().addClass("some-class");
```